# How is Euler-Lagrange equation used to find optimal solutions in minimizing a function?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, euler-lagrange-equation, minimal-surfaces

How is the Euler-Lagrange equation:

$$ L_x(t,q(t),q'(t))-\dfrac{d}{dt}L_v(t,q(t),q'(t))=0 $$

used mathematically in finding the optimal solutions of minimising a function? Can someone give me an example please?

I'm trying to determine how this formula is applicable to the study of minimal surfaces?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations#Example

Comment: It would be perhaps too involved to explain how the E-L equation works for minimal surfaces in purely elementary terms. You will need a higher dimensional version of it. In [these](http://math.colorado.edu/~jnc/MSRI.html) notes you can find a treatment that requires some effort from an undergraduate, but is is quite tractable if one really wishes to get this trough a differential geometer's perspective. A more spectacular but rather difficult for the first reading is [this](http://www.indiana.edu/~minimal/research/claynotes.pdf) survey.

Comment: Based on your questions I guess that [this](http://www.aei.mpg.de/~metzger/cm/index.html) minicourse would be quite interesting to you. See especially [Lecture 1](http://www.aei.mpg.de/~metzger/cm/minsurf-april07.pdf) there.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! The mini course looks brilliant! I'll take some time to go through it!